# Min & Max ids per range where range is N rows in ClickHouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

There may not be a way to do this in ClickHouse, but I'm hoping there is.

I have a query that returns Uint64 ids.

```
SELECT ids FROM <tableName> WHERE...
```

I want to do the following:

Divide the results of the query into chunks or arrays of N ids.

Return only the min and max ids from each chunk.

Is this possible from a ClickHouse query?

Comment: Clarification: I'm looking for the resulting batches to contain ids in order, so that the ids in the first batch are all smaller than the ids in other batches.

I need to be able to re-combine the batches in order later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We finally figured this out with some help from the ClickHouse Telegram channel. Placing here in case anyone else could use this info:

```
    SELECT min(id) AS minId, max(id) AS maxId, bucket_num, FROM (
      SELECT id, toUInt32(rowNumberInAllBlocks() / :rows) AS bucket_num FROM (
        SELECT id
        FROM <tableName>
        WHERE date_time >= :minDateTime 
        AND date_time <= :maxDateTime 
        ORDER BY id ASC))
    GROUP BY bucket_num
    ORDER BY bucket_num DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with clickhouse but I might suggest using modular math to chunk the data. 
So you can do SELECT id % n where n is the number of chunks you want and group by id % n, selecting max and min ids.

Edit: this assumes you have exactly sequential int ids. If not you'll need to assign each row a row number.

Comment: Ah I realize I didn't clarify a requirement sorry.

While this would give me evenly sized chucks, they would not be in order.

I need batch 0 to have all ids < batch1 which has ids all < batch 2 etc.